# How to create "inline if statement" with expressions in dynamic select for null checking

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, entity-framework-core

How to create "inline if statement" with expressions, in dynamic select, for null checking ?

I wrote a dynamic select LINQ expression, for a nested property of an object, but it throws an exception when it is null. so i want to check whether that property is null or not, that simple !

here is what i mean:

```
X.Where(...)
 .Select(X => new Y{
    ...
    Z = X.Titles == null ? "" : [Linq]
    ...
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

here is what i wrote

```
private static Expression GetLocalizedString(Expression stringExpression, SupportedCulture supportedCulture)
    {
        var expression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(APILocalizedString), nameof(APILocalizedString));
        
        var prop = Expression.Property(expression, nameof(APILocalizedString.SupportedCulture));
        var value = Expression.Constant(supportedCulture);
        var condition = Expression.Equal(prop, value);

        var where = Expression.Call(
            typeof (Enumerable),
            nameof(Enumerable.Where),
            new Type[] { typeof(APILocalizedString) },
            stringExpression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<APILocalizedString, bool>>(condition, expression));

        var select = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable),
            nameof(Enumerable.Select),
            new Type[] { typeof(APILocalizedString), typeof(string) },
            where,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<APILocalizedString, string>>(
                Expression.Property(expression, nameof(APILocalizedString.Text)),
                expression
            ));

        var first = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable),
            nameof(Enumerable.First),
            new Type[] { typeof(APILocalizedString) },
            stringExpression);

        var defaultIfEmpty = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable),
            nameof(Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty),
            new Type[] { typeof(string) },
            select,
            first);

        var firstOrDefault =
            Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable),
            nameof(Enumerable.FirstOrDefault),
            new Type[] { typeof(string) },
            defaultIfEmpty);


        var nullCheck = Expression.Equal(stringExpression, Expression.Constant(null, stringExpression.Type));
        var result = Expression.IfThenElse(nullCheck, Expression.Constant(""), firstOrDefault);
            
        return result;
    }
```

here is what GetLocalizedString generated:

`{IIF((X.Titles == null), "", X.Titles.Where(APILocalizedString => (APILocalizedString.SupportedCulture == EN)).DefaultIfEmpty(X.Titles.First()).Select(APILocalizedString => APILocalizedString.Text).FirstOrDefault())}`

Select expression

`... bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(property, GetLocalizedString(Expression.Property(parameter, "Titles"), SupportedCulture.EN))); ...`

and here is the error message:

`System.ArgumentException: 'Argument types do not match'`

Select property is of type String

is there any way to create an expresion like `X.Titles == null ? "" : [Linq]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression equivalent of the C# conditional `?:` operator is  [`Expression.Condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.condition?view=netframework-4.7.2). While [`Expression.IfThenElse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.ifthenelse?view=netframework-4.7.2) you are using is the equivalent of C# `if then else` block.

Both methods return [`ConditionalExpression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.conditionalexpression?view=netframework-4.7.2) with `Test`, `IfTrue` and `IfFalse` properties populated. The difference is that the result `Type` of the `Condition` is the type of the operands, while for `IfThenElse` it is `void`, hence cannot be used in query expression trees.

So the answer to your concrete question is:

```
var result = Expression.Condition(nullCheck, Expression.Constant(""), firstOrDefault);
```

---

P.S. As a side node, I'm getting several errors from your code snippet, so I had to rearrange it like this in order to get w/o error to the above line:

```
private static Expression GetLocalizedString(Expression stringExpression, SupportedCulture supportedCulture)
{
    var expression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(APILocalizedString), nameof(APILocalizedString));

    var prop = Expression.Property(expression, nameof(APILocalizedString.SupportedCulture));
    var value = Expression.Constant(supportedCulture);
    var condition = Expression.Equal(prop, value);

    var where = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        nameof(Enumerable.Where),
        new Type[] { typeof(APILocalizedString) },
        stringExpression,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<APILocalizedString, bool>>(condition, expression));

    var first = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        nameof(Enumerable.First),
        new Type[] { typeof(APILocalizedString) },
        stringExpression);

    var defaultIfEmpty = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        nameof(Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty),
        new Type[] { typeof(APILocalizedString) },
        where,
        first);

    var select = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        nameof(Enumerable.Select),
        new Type[] { typeof(APILocalizedString), typeof(string) },
        defaultIfEmpty,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<APILocalizedString, string>>(
            Expression.Property(expression, nameof(APILocalizedString.Text)),
            expression
        ));

    var firstOrDefault =
        Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable),
        nameof(Enumerable.FirstOrDefault),
        new Type[] { typeof(string) },
        select);


    var nullCheck = Expression.Equal(stringExpression, Expression.Constant(null, stringExpression.Type));
    var result = Expression.Condition(nullCheck, Expression.Constant(""), firstOrDefault);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and do you know why i get this error ? `System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'APILocalizedString' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.String' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[System.String] DefaultIfEmpty[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[System.String], System.String)''`

Comment: One question per post please. But if you ask for your code snippet, it's because the `Type` of `first` is `APILocalizedString`, and the type of `select` and `defaultIfEmpty` is `IEnumerable<string>`. That's why I rearranged the calls so `DefaultIfEmpty` goes after `Where`, and `Select` goes after `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: Any chance either of you would look at my question: [How to write Inline If Statement(SQL IIF) in EFCore Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812651/how-to-write-inline-if-statementsql-iif-in-efcore-select)